# Click on element via Javascript console

Tags: javascript, jquery, console

Imagine there is an element `#button1` on website which is watched by jQuery:

```
$('#button1').click(function(){
   console.log("you clicked");
};
```

So how do I click this `#button1` element via JavaScript console? Is there a command like `click("#button1")`? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to trigger event in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You can trigger click functio like bellow

Using JQuery

```
$('#button1').click()
```

using simple JS

```
document.getElementById('button1').click();
```

Comment: just upvoted with: $("#answer-24969935").find(".vote-up-off").click();

THX

Comment: What about using an $x("//xpath-here") expression?

Comment: I upvoted using `$("#answer-24969935").find(".js-vote-up-btn").click();` from Dev Tools Console. :)

Answer (score 8):

You can trigger a click by omitting the callback function:

```
$('#button1').click();
```

Comment: I think he needs an answer without jQuery in it.

Comment: No he doesn't, he included jQuery in his question.

Answer (score 5):

You can not click, but simulate or trigger `click`. Please refer [Creating and triggering events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events)

Comment: Can you tell me what trigger should I use for this situation? I need to see an example, then I will get it.

Comment: If you are looking for ``vanilla javascript`` solution, please refer [Triggering built-in events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events#Triggering_built-in_events). If looking for ``jQuery`` solution, other flks have already posted the answer.

Comment: Upvoting because this clarification (you can simulate but NOT trigger) would be helpful to have near the top of the thread.

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve this without jQuery:

```
document.getElementById("button1").click(); // clicks the button
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use this apart from the answers mentioned already:

```
$( "#button1" ).trigger( "click" );
```